# Why is an error arising in updating info into SQL Database from Java code?

Tags: java, mysql, database, netbeans, database-connection

I am writing the code for a sign-up page for a system. Once the button is clicked, the system will check if the user is above the age of 14. If true, the system should save all the inputted data into a SQL Database.

```
    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
       // TODO add your handling code here:
       int age = Integer.parseInt(Age_Input.getText());
       String firstname = FirstName_Input.getText();
       String surname = Surname_Input.getText();
       String email = Email_Input.getText();
       String userid = UserID_InputSignUp.getText();
       char[] pass = Password_InputSignUp.getPassword();

       if (age<14) {
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Sorry, You need to be at least 14 years to use this software... ");
           new Login_Page().setVisible(true);
           this.setVisible(false);
       } else {
           try {
              Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
              Connection connect = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/user_info", "root", "nerdswonka");
              Statement stmt = connect.createStatement();

              String query1 = "INSERT INTO user_info(user_id, password, firstname, lastname, emailid, age) VALUES('"+userid+"', "+Arrays.toString(pass)+", '"+firstname+"', '"+surname+"', '"+email+"', "+age+");";
              stmt.executeUpdate(query1);

              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Account Creation succesful!");
              stmt.close();
              connect.close();

          } catch (Exception e) {
              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error in connecting to SQL Database");
        }

          new Login_Page().setVisible(true);
          this.setVisible(false);
    }

}
```

The code isn't updating anything into the database and is simply showing JOptionPane after an exception (error ) comes. What edits can be done to the code so that values get stored into SQL?

Comment: first change: print the error message to know what it is about... better, also print the stack trace `e.printStackTrace()` - I suspect that `Arrays.toString(pass)` is **not** what the database accepts, probably you want `new String(pass)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The immediate cause of the failure is probably that your `INSERT` statement contains the following string which is not being single quoted:

```
Arrays.toString(pass)
```

*However*, you should completely abandon your current approach and instead use a prepared statement:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO user_info (user_id, password, firstname, lastname, emailid, age) " +
    "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/user_info", "root", "nerdswonka");
    PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql)) {
        ps.setString(1, userid);
        ps.setString(2, Arrays.toString(pass));
        ps.setString(3, firstname);
        ps.setString(4, surname);
        ps.setString(5, email);
        ps.setInt(6, age);

        int row = ps.executeUpdate();
        System.out.println(row); // rows inserted (should be 1)

    }
    catch (SQLException e) {
        System.err.format("SQL State: %s\n%s", e.getSQLState(), e.getMessage());
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Prepared statements do many things, one of which is handling the messy details about how to properly escape your literal data in a SQL query.  In this case, they free you from having to worry about placing single quotes around your interpolated Java strings.  Statements also prevent bad things like SQL injection from happening.

Comment: yes, beware of [Little Bobby Tables](https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/327:_Exploits_of_a_Mom) [:-)

Comment: I tried your prepared statement code. A red error line is appearing below 'user_id' in line 5 of your code. In line 2 of your code, should I also use single quotes and double quotes around the values?

Comment: @VittalKamath I fixed a typo, I had `user_id` instead of `userid`.  No, don't put single quotes anywhere.  The `VALUES` are represented in the statement by `?` placeholders.  You don't need to worry about how to format anything.

Comment: SQL State: S1009
Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0). I am getting this error after running your code...

Comment: I don't know what you are running, but my code should not be generating this error.

Comment: What does that error mean? What mistake does that sort of error point at? I must be doing something fishy...

Comment: The error is saying that your prepared statement has zero `?` placeholders, which clearly can't be the case if you are really running my code.

Comment: "VALUES (userid , Arrays.toString(pass), firstname, surname, email, age)";..... I replaced the place holders with these values. Is it right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199730/discussion-between-vittal-kamath-and-tim-biegeleisen).

Answer (score 0):

You are not printing  your exception in catch block. You can use e.printStackTrace(); to print exception first.